# Android Studio Videoview doesnt error : This vide cannot played

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to display a simple video with android studio. I want to run a video in the emulator. There is no problem with the codes. However, it gives an error.
Error: This vide cannot played

My MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    VideoView videoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);

        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/TrimVideos/Kes6.mp4";

        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(filePath));
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);

        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

        videoView.start();

    }
}
```